# Help with understanding calculus problem

Tags: calculus

This is from Stewart Calculus Metric Version 9E, Chapter 4 Problem Plus #12 :

A circular disk of radius $r$ is used in an evaporator and is rotated in a vertical plane. If it is to be partially submerged in the liquid so as to maximize the exposed wetted area of the disk, show that the center of the disk should be positioned at height $\frac{r}{\sqrt{1+\pi^{2}}}$ above the surface of the liquid.

The solution is :

[image]

I literally have no idea what 'rotated in a vertical plane' means and what that picture shows..

Comment: The disc of radius $r$ is spinning about its centre. Some of it is in the water and as it spins the central part out to a distance $x$ stays dry while the ring (annulus) between $x$ and $r$ gets wet. The white part of the disc shown, beyond the distance $x$, is the exposed wetted area of the disc I think. That is the area to maximize. If $x$ is too big you narrow the ring while if $x$ is too small you submerge too much of the disc.

Comment: Apparently "rotated in a vertical plane" is supposed to mean "mounted in a vertical plane and then spun continually around its axis". I didn't read it that way either, for what it's worth.